Getting error while fine tuning using peft
I was trying to fine tune using peft. Following is my code:
from peft import LoraConfig, TaskType, get_peft_model
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorWithPadding
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import Trainer
from datasets import load_dataset

peft_config = LoraConfig(task_type=TaskType.SEQ_2_SEQ_LM, inference_mode=False, r=2, lora_alpha=16, lora_dropout=0.01)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/mt0-large")
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
model.print_trainable_parameters()

dataset = load_dataset('imdb')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], padding="max_length", truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = predictions[:, 0]
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./mt0-large-lora",
    learning_rate=1e-3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()

I am getting following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 49
     27 training_args = TrainingArguments(
     28     output_dir="./mt0-large-lora",
     29     learning_rate=1e-3,
   (...)
     36     load_best_model_at_end=True,
     37 )
     39 trainer = Trainer(
     40     model=model,
     41     args=training_args,
   (...)
     46     compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
     47 )
---> 49 trainer.train()

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1539, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1534     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1536 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1537     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1538 )
-> 1539 return inner_training_loop(
   1540     args=args,
   1541     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1542     trial=trial,
   1543     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1544 )

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1809, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1806     self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_begin(args, self.state, self.control)
   1808 with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):
-> 1809     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1811 if (
   1812     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   1813     and not is_torch_tpu_available()
   1814     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   1815 ):
   1816     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   1817     tr_loss += tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2654, in Trainer.training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2651     return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)
   2653 with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2654     loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2656 if self.args.n_gpu > 1:
   2657     loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2679, in Trainer.compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2677 else:
   2678     labels = None
-> 2679 outputs = model(**inputs)
   2680 # Save past state if it exists
   2681 # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.
   2682 if self.args.past_index >= 0:

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1736, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1734     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1735 else:
-> 1736     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1747, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1742 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1743 # this function, and just call forward.
   1744 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1745         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1746         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1747     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1749 result = None
   1750 called_always_called_hooks = set()

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py:1080, in PeftModelForSeq2SeqLM.forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, inputs_embeds, decoder_input_ids, decoder_attention_mask, decoder_inputs_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict, **kwargs)
   1078 peft_config = self.active_peft_config
   1079 if not isinstance(peft_config, PromptLearningConfig):
-> 1080     return self.base_model(
   1081         input_ids=input_ids,
   1082         attention_mask=attention_mask,
   1083         inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
   1084         decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
   1085         decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
   1086         decoder_inputs_embeds=decoder_inputs_embeds,
   1087         labels=labels,
   1088         output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1089         output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
   1090         return_dict=return_dict,
   1091         **kwargs,
   1092     )
   1094 batch_size = input_ids.shape[0]
   1095 if decoder_attention_mask is not None:
   1096     # concat prompt attention mask

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1736, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1734     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1735 else:
-> 1736     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1747, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1742 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1743 # this function, and just call forward.
   1744 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1745         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1746         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1747     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1749 result = None
   1750 called_always_called_hooks = set()

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/mt5/modeling_mt5.py:1741, in MT5ForConditionalGeneration.forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, decoder_input_ids, decoder_attention_mask, head_mask, decoder_head_mask, cross_attn_head_mask, encoder_outputs, past_key_values, inputs_embeds, decoder_inputs_embeds, labels, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1738         decoder_attention_mask = decoder_attention_mask.to(self.decoder.first_device)
   1740 # Decode
-> 1741 decoder_outputs = self.decoder(
   1742     input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
   1743     attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
   1744     inputs_embeds=decoder_inputs_embeds,
   1745     past_key_values=past_key_values,
   1746     encoder_hidden_states=hidden_states,
   1747     encoder_attention_mask=attention_mask,
   1748     head_mask=decoder_head_mask,
   1749     cross_attn_head_mask=cross_attn_head_mask,
   1750     use_cache=use_cache,
   1751     output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1752     output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
   1753     return_dict=return_dict,
   1754 )
   1756 sequence_output = decoder_outputs[0]
   1758 # Set device for model parallelism

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1736, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1734     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1735 else:
-> 1736     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1747, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1742 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1743 # this function, and just call forward.
   1744 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1745         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1746         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1747     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1749 result = None
   1750 called_always_called_hooks = set()

File ~/venvs/fine_tuning_llama_peft/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/mt5/modeling_mt5.py:966, in MT5Stack.forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, inputs_embeds, head_mask, cross_attn_head_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    963         raise ValueError("You have to initialize the model with valid token embeddings")
    964     inputs_embeds = self.embed_tokens(input_ids)
--> 966 batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
    968 # required mask seq length can be calculated via length of past
    969 mask_seq_length = past_key_values[0][0].shape[2] + seq_length if past_key_values is not None else seq_length

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Any idea whats going wrong here? Running on my RTX GeForce 4090, GPU with 24 GB for testing purpose.
